# Remove goto/switch stataments after using ILSpy

Tags: c#, decompiling, decompiler, ilspy

I'm have some problems with using ILSpy. I'm using this tool to decomplie an DLL but it's exist to much garbages. How can i remove "goto" after using ILSpy? :'(

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "It's exist to much garbages" ... what does this mean?

Comment: Sorry. Too much "goto" statements existing. I want to simply for reading :)

Comment: ILSpy is particularly bad at handling certain types of conditional expressions, particularly those with nested assignments.  It's not the best at loops, either.  I find it is far more likely to produce ugly code with convoluted jump statements than some of its counterparts.  I second @ScottChamberlain's recommendation of dotPeek for a free alternative, or Reflector for an excellent (but commercial) solution.

Answer (score 4):

Your only option is to try a different decomplier and hope it will turn the IL code in to C# code that does not use `goto`'s.

There are many decomplilers out there on the market, another good free one like ILSpy is [DotPeek](http://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/index.html?topDP).

However, take note that it also is very possible that the original source actually put `goto`'s in the code, if that is the case there is not much you can do.

Comment: Even if the original code had `goto` statements, many decompilers will produce more structured output.  ILSpy just happens to be particularly rigid when dealing with complex conditionals and other types of code.